# ElasticSearch - search inside 3 indices from Javascript

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I would like to create an ElasticSearch model which looks inside 3 distinct indices. The code I have for just one index is:

```
var searchModel = new ElasticSearchModel({
    search_url: "http://localhost:9002/myIndex/doc/_search"  
});
var searchApp = new SearchApp({model: searchModel, el: $("#resultsNew")});
```

I would like, if possible, to specify 3 distinct search_urls and append them the same searchApp. I have tried specifying lists for the model and el properties of the SearchApp, but it did not work. Are there any workarounds for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use the below `url` to search for the type `doc` across three different `indices`.

```
search_url:http://localhost:9200/myIndex1,myIndex2,myIndex2/doc/_search
```